# Which configure logic signal to be used for the alert rule for sql database when it is down on azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, alert

I'm implementing an alert which is to notify the recipient (email) whenever the SQL database is down. I've chosen the configure logic signal on the azure "Issue failover on the database" for the alert. Is this right? So whenever the SQL database is down or not running, then it will send an alert. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a Resource Health alert as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-alert-arm-template-guide), because it will alert you and tell you why SQL Azure is down, like:

- Database is "degraded", it is unavailable due to a scaling operation or service tier change.
- Database is "Unavailable". The database is down due to known or unknown causes.

It will also report about periods of time where transient login failures occur.